# Can I use CompletableFuture.runAsync inside a spring kafka batch listener?

Tags: spring-kafka

considering my question:

```
@KafkaListener(..)
public void receive(
       List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> records,
       Acknowledgment ack) {

        records.stream().forEach(r -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(ConsumerService::process);    

        ack.acknowledge();
    }
```

What are the pitfalls? Is it a good code?

My process method will to repost to kafka if fail, in this case I can commit if or not I get some error...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You run the risk of losing messages because you are committing the offsets before the async tasks complete.  (If there is a failure (server crash, power failure etc.).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Could it be the problem of having the entire thread pool blocked at some point while more messages arrive? e.g. My custom pool has 10 threads, they are all processing the records from the previous poll, but the listener will not know this and will do a new poll. I don't know to consume in parallel at the client level (i.e, without add partitions).

Comment: You should wait for all the futures to complete before calling the `ack.acknowledge()`.

Comment: CompletableFuture allOf() would to work. Thanks, I will code some tests.